# BETWEEN operator working wrong in MySQL

Tags: mysql, between

I have a query having `BETWEEN` operator but it showing wrong results

My query-

```
SELECT * FROM register WHERE height BETWEEN  '1' AND  '6'
```

It also shows the user with height 10, 12 and 16 which is wrong. What is the problem with this query?
I have another query which work fine but is not proper way of using as it make query lengthy

```
SELECT * FROM register WHERE height > 1 AND height < 12
```

Give me idea for right way of getting the query as if more condition is added it would be hard for the query to understand and code.

Comment: what's data type of column `height`?

Comment: Why do you use strings for integer comparison? It's pretty logical that you **shouldn't** quote the numbers, isn't it?

Comment: then you use second query, or modify height column to be integer

Comment: Then coerce the columns to the appropriate types before comparing. It's not MySQL behaving weird, you just can't compare apple and oranges and expect grapes to come out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming height is an integer should it not be

```
SELECT * FROM register WHERE height BETWEEN 1 AND 6
```

You don't need the single quotes

Comment: You can't use quotes when you want to use `BETWEEN` and the field is an integer. When the field isn't an integer it should be altered to one.

Comment: as Mihai Iorga says, I would go with the second query then.  It does seem strange that height is a varchar field however....since when is height not going to be a number...?

Answer (score 1):

If:
 1. You can't or don't want to change the column type
 2. The charachters in the field are only numbers

You can change your query to:

```
SELECT * 
FROM register 
WHERE CONVERT(height, UNSIGNED INTEGER) BETWEEN 1 AND 6
```

See my example at [this SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/460d7/4).

Answer (score 0):

Check the data type of your column 'Height' it should be a int or float or double and if it is amongs above run the following query

```
SELECT * FROM register WHERE height BETWEEN 1 AND 6
```

Answer (score 0):

If the height field is not numeric, you could convert it before making you comparison.

```
SELECT * FROM register WHERE CONVERT(height, unsigned) BETWEEN 1 AND 6
```